# Why is the emulator in eclipse restarting?

Tags: android, emulation

I am following http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html
and trying to run my first android app on the emulator on my PC.
The emulator is running (started from eclipse)

I managed to lauch myFirst App via eclipse as described, although in this tutorial it should be added you have to wait minutes before the emulator is up and running.
Now my problem is that when I modify myFirstApp, and wnat to test it, that eclipse keeps starting a new emulator:

```
[2012-10-15 19:32:44 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2012-10-15 19:32:44 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2012-10-15 19:32:44 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-15 19:32:45 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-15 19:32:45 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Hobbit' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-10-15 19:32:45 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Hobbit'
```

This is extremely annoying, because of the performance penalty to launch a complete emulator.
But what is even more frustrating that I get back the very first version of MyFirstApp in this new emulator.

When I restart myself the emulator from scratch I see this in the console:

```
[2012-10-15 19:55:42 - MyFirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-10-15 19:55:42 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-10-15 19:56:57 - MyFirstApp] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch!'
```

Why? The emulator is still running at this point. This cannot be the normal way of working. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Is not it asking you to select the emulator?

Comment: Not anymore, after I marked the checkbox always to choose my one and only configured one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run -> Run Configuration in eclipse. Select your application and update the target tab at right side to "Always prompt to pick device"

Comment: It was indeed on the option: Automatically pick compatible device (my one and only). This will take a couple of minutes .....

Comment: [2012-10-15 20:21:03 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...  **This took 6 minutes; but it works!**
[2012-10-15 20:27:33 - MyFirstApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'<br>|
[2012-10-15 20:27:33 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-15 20:27:37 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...

Comment: But 4 minutes later it says:
[2012-10-15 20:31:05 - MyFirstApp] Failed to install MyFirstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-10-15 20:31:05 - MyFirstApp] (null)
[2012-10-15 20:31:07 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!

Comment: It may sound absord. But can you close the FileExplorer tab from DDMS and try again.

Comment: After a second try (a few minutes later) it worked. Without changing anything. What is the DDMS? Left I have a package explorer.Next to that the graphical layout + file editor tabs; below that the condole region. On the right an outline and a Welcome region.

Comment: Go to Window -> Open Perspective in eclipse. You should see an option DDMS. Android ships with a debugging tool called the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS), which provides port-forwarding services, screen capture on the device, thread and heap information on the device, logcat, process, and radio state information, incoming call and SMS spoofing, location data spoofing, and more. For more information you can visit http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator is running and doesnt show in Devices then try to reset adb.
In eclipse: Device tab-> Dropbown - > reset abd